# How to convert and show cell/label value from int to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, logic

I have ASP.NET project. It has GridView which is populated from my db. In the db i have column named Role and its type is integer. In DataGrid my column is TemplateField. [image: This is how my GridView looks like]

How i can show on Admin or Guest instead of 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Are you using a Label to display 1 or 2 or anything else under the column `Role` in the template field ?

Comment: you can make your `SQL query`  using `case` if 1 then 'Admin' else if '2' set `Guest` another way by using `OnRowDataBound` set value

Comment: I'm using label for displaying roles, but later i will use drop down list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OnRowDataBound in your ASPX and handle it in your CS file. Sample below

In your ASPX File

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

In your CS File

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Cell#5 because your Role appears in that field (Index starts with 0)
        if(e.Row.Cells[5].Text.Equals(1))
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "Admin";
        if(e.Row.Cells[5].Text.Equals(2))
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "Guest";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is use full.

Comment: There is a problem, on RowDataBound method, text is always ""(empty string) why is that

Comment: Can you post your ASPX snippet, along with your field mappings?

Comment: I found another way already, first i created method
 public static string ConvertRow(string role)
        {
            var rolee = (role == "1") ? "Admin" : "User";
            return rolee;
        }
and then i say like this: 
<asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%# TimeTracker.Repository.Extension.ConvertRow((Eval("UserRole")).ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>

and it work fine. I appreciate your effort. Thanks.